# biblatex: merge the list of shorthands into the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, sorting

Using `biblatex`, is it possible to merge the list of shorthands into the bibliography?

The goal is to have a single alphabetical list of references, regardless of whether they are cited in shorthand notation or not.

For example, the entry for a certain lexicon cited as LIV should appear at 'L-' in the general bibliography, like this:

> ...
>
> Liberman (1982) ...
>
> LIV = Rix, Helmut et al. (2001): Lexikon der indogermanischen Verben ...
>
> Luick (1914) ...
>
> ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This solution changes the sorting scheme, and hence requires `biber` as the backend.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}{}{%
        \printfield{shorthand}\addspace =\addspace}}

\DeclareSortingScheme{nyt}{%
    \sort{\field{presort}}
    \sort[final]{\field{sortkey}}
    \sort{%
        \field{shorthand}
        \name{sortname}\name{author}\name{editor}\name{translator}
        \field{sorttitle}\field{title}}
    \sort{\field{sortyear}\field{year}}
    \sort{\field{sorttitle}\field{title}}
    \sort{%
        \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
        \literal{0000}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{bertram,
    shorthand = {GrI},
    author = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
    title = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces},
    journaltitle = {J.~Amer. Math. Soc.},
    volume = {9},
    number = {2},
    date = {1996},
    pages = {529--571}}
@Article{gillies,
    author = {Gillies, Alexander},
    title = {Herder and the Preparation of Goethe's Idea of World Literature},
    journaltitle = {Publications of the English Goethe Society},
    volume = {9},
    date = {1933},
    pages = {46--67}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{bertram} and \cite{gillies}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get this working! I had to jump through some hoops to install `biber`, though, because it's not packaged for Debian/Ubuntu yet (as far as I can see). I ended up installing this binary: (http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/current/binaries/Linux/), this version of biblatex: (http://packages.debian.org/unstable/main/biblatex) and these dependencies: (http://people.debian.org/~jhr/).