# Overriding keys for references

Tags: bibliographies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can one “manually override” Bibtex's choice of citation keys by adding a field to the entry?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102/can-one-manually-override-bibtexs-choice-of-citation-keys-by-adding-a-field-t)

I am using BiBTeX and would like to achieve the following:
I am usually using a derivative of the *alpha* style, but for some entries I would like to define my own (preferred key). For example, I would like to reference EGAI as [EGAI] rather than [Gro60]. (If you don't know what EGA is, does not matter. The point is, that it is a book universally known in algebraic geometry as "EGA"). 
I tried various tricks such as defining the entry "key" without success. Perhaps complicating the question the fact that I would like to keep the rest of the keys as in *alpha*. An alternative solution I am willing to consider is a style where the original biblio entry would have to define the key to be used for everything, although this would be a last resort. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I guess it would help if you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Furthermore you may like to take a look at [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) it’s a very powerful bibliography package.

Comment: Is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102/can-one-manually-override-bibtexs-choice-of-citation-keys-by-adding-a-field-t related?

Comment: @JosephWright: You are right. I did a search before posting the question, but did not find that post.  Interestingly the suggestions are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shorthand key in [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) works here, at least with the bibtex or bibtex8 backends. Haven't tried the natbib option linked above, and there's a [very similar question at this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17905/biblatex-merge-the-list-of-shorthands-into-the-bibliography) with a more complex answer that works with biber. MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ega.bib}
@book{EGAI,
 crossref = {Gro60}
}
@book{Gro60,
 title = {\'El\'ements de g\'eom\'etrie alg\'ebrique},
 author = {Alexander Grothendieck},
 year = 1960,
 shorthand = {EGAI}
}
@book{Ste99,
 title = {Calculus},
 author = {James Stewart},
 year = 1999,
 edition = 4th,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[citestyle=alphabetic,bibstyle=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\bibliography{ega}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Most papers wouldn't cite both \cite{EGAI} and \cite{Ste99} in one sentence.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I compile your example with `biber` instead of `bibtex`, it displays `Gro60`, not `EGAI`.

Comment: Odd. Looking for a solution; never used biblatex before now.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Under `biber` the `shorthand` field isn't inherited from a cross-referenced entry, though it is possible to set that up. I'm not sure `crossref` is necessary here. The `shorthand` field overrides the default `label`. The OP referred to "keys", but I'm guessing he just meant the alphabetic label.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer....

Comment: @SándorKovács Thanks for clarifying. In Mike's answer, you would then just cite `Gro60` directly to override the default `label` with `shorthand`.