# How to print shortauthor in the references as well?

Tags: biblatex

I have several sources in my reference list that I need to abbreviate for citing them (e.g. (IEA 2005)). I do this with biblatex and {shortauthor}, which works great. Still, how can I show the abbreviation also in the reference list, making it look something like:

> IEA (2005): International Energy Agency. *World Energy Outlook
>   2005*....

or maybe even better:

> IEA - International Energy Agency (2005):  *World Energy Outlook
>   2005*....

instead of:

> International Energy Agency (2005). *World Energy Outlook 2005*....

Comment: Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: Which bibliography style are you using?

Comment: domwass answer is already perfect, thank you guys!

Answer (score 14):

You could redefine the bibmacro `begentry`:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{iea,
author = {{International Energy Agency}},
title = {World Energy Outlook},
shortauthor = {IEA},
date = {2005}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}

\usepackage[
    style=authoryear,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
    \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
        {}
        {\printnames{shortauthor}%
         \addspace\textendash\space}}
\begin{document}
\cite{companion,iea}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sir, this does not only work perfectly well, you were also incredibly fast! Thank you very, very much!

Comment: Might want to change the sorting scheme as well. The same problem but with `shorthand` was covered in a [previous question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17905/4483).

Comment: @Ben, if this solves your problem, please consider to accept my answer (this is not the same as upvoting).

Comment: @domwass I have used your solution together with http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17905/4483
Now I have a follow-up question:
how can I make the `shortauthor` being replaced by a dash, when multiple entries occur?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> \renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
>     \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
>          {}
>          {\printnames{shortauthor}%
>          \addspace\textendash\space}}
> ```

Thank you, this helped me a lot.

I share with you my solution for author/shortauthor in combination with editor/shorteditor:

```
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
    \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
        {\ifnameundef{shorteditor}
            {}
            {\printnames{shorteditor}%
             \addspace\textendash\space}}
         {\printnames{shortauthor}%
          \addspace\textendash\space}}
```