# How to print shortauthor in the references as well? Further question

Tags: biblatex

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47398/how-to-print-shortauthor-in-the-references-as-well) lockstep asked how to additionally use the shortauthor field in the bibliography.

I, however, would like to completely replace the author field with shortauthor.

Instead of

> International Energy Agency (2005). World Energy Outlook 2005....

and

> IEA - International Energy Agency (2005): World Energy Outlook 2005....

I prefer

> IEA (2005): International Energy Agency. World Energy Outlook 2005....

Example code

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{iea,
author = {{International Energy Agency}},
title = {World Energy Outlook},
shortauthor = {IEA},
date = {2005}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}

\usepackage[
    style=authoryear,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{companion,iea}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! Don't you need a `\printbibliography` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, of course! I just edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution here has to be slightly more involved. We have to modify the `author` macro quite a bit.

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \ifnameundef{shortauthor}% <-------- this is new: prefer shortauthor
          {\printnames{author}}
          {\printnames{shortauthor}}
        \iffieldundef{authortype}
          {\setunit{\addspace}}
          {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}%
  \ifnameundef{shortauthor}% <-------- this is new: delay real author until after year
    {}
    {\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
     \printnames{author}%
     \printunit{\newunitpunct}\newblock}
  }
\makeatother
```

We added two `\ifnameundef{shortauthor}` blocks: One to prefer `shortauthor` over `author` at the beginning and one to print the `author` after the year if we had a `shortauthor`.

In the MWE we also modified the `editor` macro in a similar fashion

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{iea,
author = {{International Energy Agency}},
title = {World Energy Outlook},
shortauthor = {IEA},
date = {2005}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}

\usepackage[
    style=authoryear,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
          {\printnames{author}}
          {\printnames{shortauthor}}
        \iffieldundef{authortype}
          {\setunit{\addspace}}
          {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}%
  \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
    {}
    {\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
     \printnames{author}%
     \printunit{\newunitpunct}\newblock}}

\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\ifnameundef{shorteditor}
          {\printnames{editor}}
          {\printnames{shorteditor}}
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}%
  \ifnameundef{shorteditor}
    {}
    {\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
     \printnames{editor}%
     \printunit{\newunitpunct}\newblock}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\cite{companion,iea}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE showing: IEA (2005): International Energy Agency. World Energy Outlook.]

Comment: Thank you moewe for your fast and perfectly working response.