# add shortauthor to references (after author)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I need to amend the references to include the "shortauthor" in biblatex. My question is almost identical to

[How to print shortauthor in the references as well?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47398/how-to-print-shortauthor-in-the-references-as-well)

but I need the reference to be of the form

> World Health Organization [WHO]. (2016). ...

Right now, it is

> World Health Organization. (2016). ...

and `\begentry` only lets you amend the beginning of the entry. I use biblatex with `style=apa`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `biblatex-apa` you only need

```
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifnameundef{author}
    {\usebibmacro{labeltitle}}
    {\printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printfield{nameaddon}%
     \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
       {}
       {\setunit*{\addspace}%
        \printtext[brackets]{\printnames{shortauthor}}}%
     \ifnameundef{with}
       {}
       {\setunit{}\addspace\mkbibparens{\printtext{\bibstring{with}\addspace}%
        \printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{with}}
        \setunit*{\addspace}}}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{labelyear+extrayear}}
```

Where we just added the part starting with `\ifnameundef{shortauthor}`.

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{scrartcl}
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{iea,
author = {{International Energy Agency}},
title = {World Energy Outlook},
shortauthor = {IEA},
date = {2005}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}

\usepackage[
    style=apa,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifnameundef{author}
    {\usebibmacro{labeltitle}}
    {\printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printfield{nameaddon}%
     \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
       {}
       {\setunit*{\addspace}%
        \printtext[brackets]{\printnames{shortauthor}}}%
     \ifnameundef{with}
       {}
       {\setunit{}\addspace\mkbibparens{\printtext{\bibstring{with}\addspace}%
        \printnames[apaauthor][-\value{listtotal}]{with}}
        \setunit*{\addspace}}}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{labelyear+extrayear}}

\begin{document}
\cite{companion,iea}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: this solution sadly creates a new problem for me. The bibliography looks like this after adding the shortname with your solution: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0stQB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0stQB.png) How do I get the follwoing notation back with just the [MSB NRW] added: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTg5Q.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTg5Q.png)

Comment: @TrizZm4ster I think this should be asked in a new question (which should include an example document that reproduces the undesirable output).

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the amount of references in your `.bib` but wouldn't it be simpler to manually shortcode your entry ?

Something like this should do the trick just fine :

```
 @book{hello,
 Title={Hello},
 Author={World Health {Organization [WHO]}}
}
```

Where the double `{}` is used to trick biblatex into thinking that "Organization [WHO]" is a single word.

Comment: I am completely fine with shortcoding. However, your example returns "Organization [FSO], 2016"

in citations and bibliography. Also, I already have 
    `Author={{World Health Organization}}`

in double braces

Comment: I didn't have thought of that, sorry.