# Getting correct sorting using shortauthor and shorthand in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, formatting, biber

I've been using the following answers in my document:

- [How to print shortauthor in the references as well?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47398/how-to-print-shortauthor-in-the-references-as-well)
- [biblatex: merge the list of shorthands into the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17905/biblatex-merge-the-list-of-shorthands-into-the-bibliography)
- [Different font for specific bibliography item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289041/different-font-for-specific-bibliography-item) (present, but not used in the minimal example)

This doesn't work correctly when I have multiple works from the same `author` (and the same `shortauthor`).

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex} 

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
    \ifkeyword{Key}{\sffamily}{}%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}{}{%
        \printfield{shorthand}:\space}%
    \ifnameundef{shortauthor}%
    {}%
    {\printnames{shortauthor}%
        \addspace\textendash\space}}

\DeclareSortingScheme{nyt}{%
    \sort{\field{presort}}
    \sort[final]{\field{sortkey}}
    \sort{%
        \field{shorthand}
        \name{sortname}\name{author}\name{editor}\name{translator}
        \field{sorttitle}\field{title}}
    \sort{\field{sortyear}\field{year}}
    \sort{\field{sorttitle}\field{title}}
    \sort{%
        \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
        \literal{0000}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @report{IATA2009,
        author = {{International Air Transport Association}},
        date = {2009-03},
        title = {Standard Schedules Information Manual},
        shortauthor = {IATA}
    }


    @report{IATA2015,
        author = {{International Air Transport Association}},
        date = {2015-08},
        title = {Worldwide Slot Guidelines},
        shortauthor = {IATA}
    }

    @report{IATA2016,
        author = {{International Air Transport Association}},
        date = {2015-09},
        title = {Airport Guide},
        shortauthor = {IATA},
        shorthand = {Shorthand}
        }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

As a result, it gives:

> IATA – International Air Transport Association (2009). *Standard Schedules In-
>   formation Manual.*
>   IATA – — (2015a). *Worldwide Slot Guidelines.*
>   Shorthand: IATA – — (2015b). *Airport Guide.*

What it should give is:

> IATA – International Air Transport Association (2009). *Standard Schedules In-
>   formation Manual.*
>   — (2015a). *Worldwide Slot Guidelines.*
>   Shorthand: — (2015b). *Airport Guide.*

(Actually, I'm not sure about whether the last line should rather be

> Shorthand: IATA – International Air Transport Association (2015b). *Airport Guide.*

Which one looks better?)

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \ifkeyword{Key}{\sffamily}{}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \printfield{shorthand}%
     \addcolon\space}%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}} or test {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}}}%
    {}%
    {\printnames{shortauthor}%
     \addspace\textendash\space}}
\makeatother
```

With this definition we don't print the `shortauthor` field if `bbx:dashcheck` returns true (i.e. if the last `author` was the same).
If we have a `shorthand` we automatically print the name no matter if it coincides with the last name (I liked that better, you can turn off that behaviour by commenting out the line `\global\undef\bbx@lasthash`).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex} 

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \ifkeyword{Key}{\sffamily}{}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \printfield{shorthand}%
     \addcolon\space}%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}} or test {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}}}%
    {}%
    {\printnames{shortauthor}%
     \addspace\textendash\space}}
\makeatother

\DeclareSortingScheme{nyt}{%
    \sort{\field{presort}}
    \sort[final]{\field{sortkey}}
    \sort{%
        \field{shorthand}
        \name{sortname}\name{author}\name{editor}\name{translator}
        \field{sorttitle}\field{title}}
    \sort{\field{sortyear}\field{year}}
    \sort{\field{sorttitle}\field{title}}
    \sort{%
        \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
        \literal{0000}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@report{IATA2009,
  author = {{International Air Transport Association}},
  date = {2009-03},
  title = {Standard Schedules Information Manual},
  shortauthor = {IATA},
}

@report{IATA2015,
  author = {{International Air Transport Association}},
  date = {2015-08},
  title = {Worldwide Slot Guidelines},
  shortauthor = {IATA},
}

@report{IATA2016,
  author = {{International Air Transport Association}},
  date = {2015-09},
  title = {Airport Guide},
  shortauthor = {IATA},
  shorthand = {Shorthand},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]