# Biblatex: Latin letters in citation, latin and cyrillic in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cyrillic, russian

I'm looking for a way to cite Russian authors using their transliterated name in the citation (e.g. Dostojevski 2014), but with a bibliography entry like this:

**Dostojevski = Достоевский, Фёдор Михайлович 2014.** Двойник. Москва: Aegitas.

So far, I have managed to modify my bibliography to look like this:

**Достоевский, Фёдор Михайлович 2014.** Двойник. Москва: Aegitas.

Is there a possibility to (manually) add transliterations (of names in a different script) to bibliography entries in the .bib-file, to then use them for in-text citation and in the beginning of the respective bibliography entry as shown above?

Here is the code (right now the Cyrillic name doesn't even show in the citation, but only in the bibliography):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{dostoevski2014,
  title={Двойник},
  author={Фёдор Михайлович Достоевский},
  year={2014},
  location = {Москва},
  publisher={Aegitas},
  langid={russian},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[russian, english, estonian]{babel}

\usepackage[bibencoding=auto, backend=biber, babel = other, style=authoryear, dashed=false, citestyle=authoryear-comp, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage{xpatch, filecontents}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\bibliography{\jobname}


\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

\xpretobibmacro{author}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{author}{\egroup}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\egroup}{}{}

\begin{document}

Names in Cyrillic letters don't even show. (\cite{dostoevski2014})

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/317477/35864

Comment: Currently the easiest way is probably via `shortauthor`. But there is ongoing work on a multiscript version of `biblatex` that should make this easier (no ETA as of now, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/416, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commits/multiscript)