# How to cite a few Russian sources in an English document

Tags: bibliographies, biber, cyrillic, russian

The following code works, when the citation style is `authoryear`, but intermingles author's name and its translation in the bibliography when it is numeric:

```
\begin{filecontents}[force]{test.bib}
@ARTICLE{Smi-39,
  AUTHOR       = {{\foreignlanguage{russian}{\fontspec{DejaVuSerif.ttf}{Смирнов, Н.}}} [Smirnov, N.]},
  sortname     = {Smirnov, N.},
  shortauthor  = {Smirnov},
  TITLE        = {{\foreignlanguage{russian}{\fontspec{DejaVuSerif.ttf}{Об уклонениях эмпирической кривой распределения}}} [On deviation of the empirical distribution curve]},
  sorttitle    = {On deviation of the empirical distribution curve},
  YEAR         = {1939},
  JOURNAL      = {{\foreignlanguage{russian}{\fontspec{DejaVuSerif.ttf}{Мат. Сборник}}} [Math. Collect.]},
  volume       = {6(48)},
  number       = {1},
  pages        = {3-26},
  langid       = {russian},
  url          = {http://www.mathnet.ru/links/9c480a97757553ea3504fc444cde8430/sm5810.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents}
    
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX spellcheck = en_GB
% !BIB program = biber
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[british]{scrartcl}
    
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\usepackage[main=british,russian]{babel}%foreign language support
%\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=UTF8,sorting=none,style=authoryear]{biblatex}%works
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=UTF8,sorting=none,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}%fails
\usepackage{csquotes}%context-sensitive quotes, required for biblatex
\usepackage{fontspec}% font selecting commands
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}% For Cyrillic fonts with pdflatex.
    
\addbibresource{test.bib}
    
\title{Test}
\author{Tester }
\date{\today}
    
\begin{document}
    
\maketitle
    
Test the quick brown fox\parencite{Smi-39} jumps over the lazy dog.   
      
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]
    
\end{document}
```

What is the problem here?

And on a side-issue: Can anybody suggest a font whose Cyrillic letters fit better to the kp-fonts of the main text than DejaVuSerif?

Comment: I don't think adding LaTeX code to your .bib file is a viable approach, in the long term … Have you seen this thread? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317477/biblatex-author-aliases-for-sources-in-another-script

Comment: @Ingmar: Yes, that is one of the sources for my code above, another is https://texwelt.de/fragen/25730/russischer-titel-im-biblatex-literaturverzeichnis. I have since learned that \babelfont[russian]{rm}{Liberation Serif} can select the font for the whole text. And Liberation does look better with kp...

Comment: you can try with more braces: `AUTHOR       = {{{\foreignlanguage{russian}{\fontspec{DejaVuSerif.ttf}{Смирнов, Н.}}} [Smirnov, N.]}},` .

Answer (score 1):

With Ulrike's hint a working version becomes:

```
    \begin{filecontents}[force]{test.bib}
  @ARTICLE{Smi-39,
    AUTHOR       = {{{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Смирнов, Н.}} [Smirnov, N.]}},
    sortname     = {Smirnov, N.},
    shortauthor  = {Smirnov},
    TITLE        = {{{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Об уклонениях эмпирической кривой распределения}} [1 On deviation of the empirical distribution curve]}},
    sorttitle    = {On deviation of the empirical distribution curve},
    YEAR         = {1939},
    JOURNAL      = {{{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Мат. Сборник}} [Math. Collect.]}},
    volume       = {6(48)},
    number       = {1},
    pages        = {3-26},
    langid       = {russian},
    url          = {http://www.mathnet.ru/links/9c480a97757553ea3504fc444cde8430/sm5810.pdf},
  }

@ARTICLE{Kol-33,
  AUTHOR       = {Kolmogorov, A.},
  TITLE        = {Sulla Determinazione Empirica di una Legge di Distribuzione [On the empirical determination of a distribution law]},
  YEAR         = {1933},
  JOURNAL      = {Giorn. Ist. Ital. Attuar.},
  volume       = {4},
  number       = {1},
  pages        = {83-91},
}

\end{filecontents}

% -*- TeX:UK -*-
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX spellcheck = en_GB
% !BIB program = biber
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[british]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\usepackage[main=british,russian]{babel}%foreign language support
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=UTF8,sorting=none,style=authoryear]{biblatex}%bibliography
%\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=UTF8,sorting=none,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}%bibliography
\usepackage{csquotes}%context-sensitive quotes, required for biblatex
%\usepackage{fontspec}% font selecting commands
%\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}% For Cyrillic fonts with pdflatex.

\babelfont[russian]{rm}{Liberation Serif}
\babelfont[russian]{sf}{Liberation Sans}
\babelfont[russian]{tt}{Liberation Mono}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\title{Test}
\author{Tester }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

The quick brown fox\parencite{Kol-33,Smi-39} jumps over the lazy dog.

\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]

\end{document}
```