# Customise citation in text

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have a little problem citing international organisations.

I would like to have the full name in the bibliography (e.g. Bank of International Settlements), 
but an abbreviation in the text (here: "BIS"), so then as a reference e.g.
(BIS, 20xx).

Any suggestion how that might work using BibLaTeX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the option `shortauthor`.

You should create a bib entry of this kind in `your-file.bib`:

```
@manual{baselI1988,
    title={International convergence of capital measurement and capital standards},
    author={{Bank for International Settlements}},
    year={1988},
    shortauthor = {BIS},   
    %sortname = {BIS}, this line is need if you use the \renewbibmacro commented in the MWE  
    url={http://www.bis.org/publ/bcbs04a.pdf}
    }
```

and then use it in a code like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

% biblatex
\usepackage[style=authoryear, natbib=true, backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

% this \renewbibmacro needed only if you want the acronym before the author in the bibliography
    %\makeatletter
%\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
%   \ifkeyword{Key}{\sffamily}{}%
%   \iffieldundef{shorthand}
%   {}
%   {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
%       \printfield{shorthand}%
%       \addcolon\space}%
%   \ifboolexpr{test {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}} or test {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}}}%
%   {}%
%   {\printnames{shortauthor}%
%       \addspace\textendash\space}}
    %\makeatother
%-------

% add bibliography database
\addbibresource{your-file.bib}

\begin{document}

Citation of the type Author (year): \citet{baselI1988} \\
Citation of the type (Author, year): \citep{baselI1988}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

(the `\renewbibmacro` is taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289060/101651)).

Here the result:

[image: Citations]

[image: Bibliography]

Comment: and this is how it works! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jannik You are welcome! If my answer met your needs, don't forget to accept it by clicking the checkmark, in that way your question won't appear in the UNanswered list (but it will remain in the general one) and we both will earn reputation, thank you!